# Count the days and stop counting if the status is different from the previous one. Then count again

Tags: r

Count the days and stop counting if the status is different from the previous one. Then count the new state and stop counting if the state is different again.

In other words: I have several patients with a disease who come to control, and each control is recorded in a row.
The variable ID is the ID associated with the patient. If at the check-up it does not show pain it is 0 otherwise 1.

My goal is to count from the first check-up day how many days she does not have or has a symptom. So, for example, count from the first day of control, for how many days it has value 0 and then stop when it has value 1 and count for how many days it will have value 1. Then I stop when the value will be 0 again and continue to count.

(In the picture I have created an excel column called DAYS where I show an example of the count I would like to obtain.)

```
dput(head(Cartel3,15))
structure(list(ID = c("ID1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "ID2", NA, NA), DATE = structure(c(1226275200, 1229904000, 
1236902400, 1238716800, 1264118400, 1303430400, 1311897600, 1343952000, 
1351814400, 1359676800, 1397174400, NA, 1110931200, 1113868800, 
1129593600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    STATUS = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", NA, "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

head(Cartel3,20)
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   ID    DATE                STATUS
   <chr> <dttm>              <chr> 
 1 ID1   2008-11-10 00:00:00 0     
 2 NA    2008-12-22 00:00:00 0     
 3 NA    2009-03-13 00:00:00 1     
 4 NA    2009-04-03 00:00:00 1     
 5 NA    2010-01-22 00:00:00 0     
 6 NA    2011-04-22 00:00:00 0     
 7 NA    2011-07-29 00:00:00 0     
 8 NA    2012-08-03 00:00:00 0     
 9 NA    2012-11-02 00:00:00 0     
10 NA    2013-02-01 00:00:00 0     
11 NA    2014-04-11 00:00:00 0     
12 ID2   2005-03-16 00:00:00 0     
13 NA    2005-04-19 00:00:00 0     
14 NA    2005-10-18 00:00:00 0     
15 NA    2005-12-05 00:00:00 0     
16 NA    2006-03-16 00:00:00 1     
17 NA    2006-06-15 00:00:00 1     
18 NA    2007-04-02 00:00:00 0     
19 NA    2007-05-16 00:00:00 0     
20 NA    2007-07-26 00:00:00 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dplyr way

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table) # rleid() function

df %>% fill(ID) %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(d1 = rleid(STATUS)) %>%
  group_by(ID, d1) %>%
  mutate(d = ifelse(row_number() == 1 & d1 != 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% mutate(d = ifelse(row_number() == n(), 1, d),
                          d2 = difftime(DATE, first(DATE), units = "days"),
                          d2 = c(0, diff(d2)),
                          d1 = c(1L, d1[-n()])) %>%
  group_by(ID, d1) %>%
  mutate(DAYS = cumsum(d2)*d) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-d, -d1, -d2)

# A tibble: 14 x 4
   ID    DATE                STATUS  DAYS
   <chr> <dttm>              <chr>  <dbl>
 1 ID1   2008-11-10 00:00:00 0          0
 2 ID1   2008-12-22 00:00:00 0          0
 3 ID1   2009-03-13 00:00:00 1        123
 4 ID1   2009-04-03 00:00:00 1          0
 5 ID1   2010-01-22 00:00:00 0        315
 6 ID1   2011-04-22 00:00:00 0          0
 7 ID1   2011-07-29 00:00:00 0          0
 8 ID1   2012-08-03 00:00:00 0          0
 9 ID1   2012-11-02 00:00:00 0          0
10 ID1   2013-02-01 00:00:00 0          0
11 ID1   2014-04-11 00:00:00 0       1540
12 ID2   2005-03-16 00:00:00 0          0
13 ID2   2005-04-19 00:00:00 0          0
14 ID2   2005-10-18 00:00:00 0        216
```

dput used

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("ID1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "ID2", NA, NA), DATE = structure(c(1226275200, 1229904000, 
1236902400, 1238716800, 1264118400, 1303430400, 1311897600, 1343952000, 
1351814400, 1359676800, 1397174400, 1110931200, 1113868800, 1129593600
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), STATUS = c("0", 
"0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

> df
# A tibble: 14 x 3
   ID    DATE                STATUS
   <chr> <dttm>              <chr> 
 1 ID1   2008-11-10 00:00:00 0     
 2 NA    2008-12-22 00:00:00 0     
 3 NA    2009-03-13 00:00:00 1     
 4 NA    2009-04-03 00:00:00 1     
 5 NA    2010-01-22 00:00:00 0     
 6 NA    2011-04-22 00:00:00 0     
 7 NA    2011-07-29 00:00:00 0     
 8 NA    2012-08-03 00:00:00 0     
 9 NA    2012-11-02 00:00:00 0     
10 NA    2013-02-01 00:00:00 0     
11 NA    2014-04-11 00:00:00 0     
12 ID2   2005-03-16 00:00:00 0     
13 NA    2005-04-19 00:00:00 0     
14 NA    2005-10-18 00:00:00 0
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll make some changes to the code you gave me to fit the rest of the data, but the input is what I wanted! Thanks very much again!!

Answer (score 1):

This will accomplish the task.

```
df=data.frame(id=c("Id1", rep(NA, 10), "Id2", rep(NA, 9)), date=dates, status=c(0,0,1,1,rep(0, 11), 1, 1, rep(0, 4)))
dates=as.Date(c(c("10/11/08", "22/12/08", "13/03/09", "03/04/09", "22/01/10", "22/04/11", "29/07/11", "03/08/12", "02/11/12", "01/02/13", "11/04/14"), c("16/03/05", "19/04/05", "18/10/05", "05/12/05", "16/03/06", "15/06/06", "02/04/07", "16/05/07", "26/07/07", "09/08/07")), format="%d/%m/%y")
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1=fill(df, 1)
df2=data.frame()
for (i in unique(df1$id)) {
  tmp=filter(df1, id==i)
  count=0
  streak=c()
  for (i in 2:nrow(tmp)) {
    count=count+tmp$date[i]-tmp$date[i-1]
    if (i==nrow(tmp)) {
      streak[i]=count
      break
    }
    if (tmp$status[i]==tmp$status[i-1]) {
      streak[i]=NA
    } else {
      streak[i]=count
      count=0
    }
  }
  tmp[,"days"]=streak
  tmp[2:nrow(tmp),"id"]=NA
  df2=bind_rows(df2, tmp)
}

     id       date status days
1   Id1 2008-11-10      0   NA
2  <NA> 2008-12-22      0   NA
3  <NA> 2009-03-13      1  123
4  <NA> 2009-04-03      1   NA
5  <NA> 2010-01-22      0  315
6  <NA> 2011-04-22      0   NA
7  <NA> 2011-07-29      0   NA
8  <NA> 2012-08-03      0   NA
9  <NA> 2012-11-02      0   NA
10 <NA> 2013-02-01      0   NA
11 <NA> 2014-04-11      0 1540
12  Id2 2005-03-16      0   NA
13 <NA> 2005-04-19      0   NA
14 <NA> 2005-10-18      0   NA
15 <NA> 2005-12-05      0   NA
16 <NA> 2006-03-16      1  365
17 <NA> 2006-06-15      1   NA
18 <NA> 2007-04-02      0  382
19 <NA> 2007-05-16      0   NA
20 <NA> 2007-07-26      0   NA
21 <NA> 2007-08-09      0  129
```